# How to get all documents from two different collections in Firebase?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase Cloud database. I have two collections `users1` and `users2`. Both of them have the field `full_name`. I want to get all documents from collection `user1` and collection `user2` sorted by `Query.Direction.ASCENDING`. For the first collection I do:

```
db.document(groupPath).collection("users1").orderBy("full_name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    // code
});
```

The trivial way would be to add another `addSnapshotListener` in the `users1`'s `addSnapshotListener`. Is there a way to do it with one `addSnapshotListener`?

Comment: If you have two collections with different names, it will require two queries. There is no avoiding this without restructuring your data or making a copy of everything into a single collection.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Firestore  doesn't support reading from two collection at one time , you'll need at least two functions.

You have to implement two separate documents `(user1,user2)` inside **one** collection `(Users)`